# How to remove white space from Phone Number in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't remove white space from Phone Number in iOS app.

Here is my codes.

```
        ABMultiValueRef multiPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        for (CFIndex iPhone = 0; iPhone < ABMultiValueGetCount(multiPhones); iPhone++)
        {
            CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiPhones, iPhone);
            NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *) phoneNumberRef;
            if (phoneNumber == nil) {
                phoneNumber = @"";
            }
            if (phoneNumber.length == 0) continue;

            // phone number = (217) 934-3234
            phoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
            phoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
            phoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
            phoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

            // phone number = 217 9343234
            [phoneNumbers addObject:phoneNumber];
        }
```

I expect to get without white space. But it is not removed from the phone number.
How can I fix? Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Hey, trojanfoe. I couldn't get this answer on any blogs. Why did you mark as duplicated?

Comment: Because the answer you accepted provides the exact same solution!  Please search before posting to avoid filling the site with the same questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something a lot simpler than what you're currently doing with [`NSCharacterSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/). Here's how:

`NSCharacterSet` defines a collection of characters. There are a few standard ones, such as [`decimalDigitsCharacterSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/decimalDigitCharacterSet) and [`alphaNumericCharacterSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/alphanumericCharacterSet).

There's also a neat method called [`invertedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSCharacterSet/invertedSet) which returns a character set with all of the characters *not* included in the current one. Now, we need just one more bit of information.

`NSString` has a method called [`componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:), which gives you back an [`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/) of the parts of the string, broken up around the characters in the characterSet you supply.

[`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray) has a complementary function, [`componentsJoinedWithString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/componentsJoinedByString:) which you can use to turn the elements of an array (back) into a string. See where this is going?

First, define a character set that we want to include in our final output:

`NSCharacterSet *digits = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];`

Now, get everything else.

`NSCharacterSet *illegalCharacters = [digits invertedSet]`

Once we have the character set that we want, we can break out the string and reconstruct it:

```
NSArray *components = [phoneNumber componentsSeperatedByCharactersInSet:illegalCharacters];

NSString *output = [components componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

That should give you the correct output. Four lines, and you're done:

```
NSCharacterSet *digits = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
NSCharacterSet *illegalCharacters = [digits invertedSet];
NSArray *components = [phoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:illegalCharacters];

NSString *output = [components componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

You can use the `whitespaceCharacterSet` do do something similar to trim whitespace off of strings.

NSHipster has [a great article](http://nshipster.com/nscharacterset/) about this, too.

**EDIT:**

If you want to include other symbols, such as the `+` prefix or parenthesis, you can create custom character sets with [`characterSetWithCharactersInString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/characterSetWithCharactersInString:). If you have two character sets, such as the decimal digits and the custom one you created, you could use [`NSMutableCharacterSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableCharacterSet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableCharacterSet/formUnionWithCharacterSet:) to modify the character set you have to include other characters.

Comment: Whoops, there you go.

Comment: This is not working.
An error occurred on this line.
NSArray *components = [phoneNumber componentsSeparatedByString:illegalCharacters];

Comment: What's not working? Does it compile? Does it give incorrect output?

Comment: It is compiled successfully. But this line gives me this error.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFCharacterSet length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d13aa90'

Comment: @WilliamG.  `componentsSeparatedByString`?!?!

Comment: When I use componentsSeperatedByCharactersInSet. It gives me compile error.
No such method.

Comment: There's definitely a `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` method. I had the same issue when copying my code that I typed here into Xcode. You might have to let autocomplete type it out for you. Let me put some documentation links into my answer.

Comment: You spelled it wrong in your code snippet (seperated vs separated)

Comment: That makes sense - whoops.

Comment: Thank you Moshe. It is working well. But there was a spell error. componentsSeperatedByCharactersInSet should be replaced into componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet in your code.
This is the best answer :) Thank you very much, Moshe.
But one more problem, if there is a + prefix in phone number, I want to keep it. I want to remove only (, ), - and white space.
Could you help me?

Comment: You're welcome. (If you like this answer and you think I deserve it, please use the checkmark to indicate this is correct.) For your other problem, you can use NSCharacterSet to create a new set with that `+` character in it. Then, make a union of that set with the `decimalDigitsCharacterSet`. *Then* invert the set and continue as we did earlier.

Comment: Could you leave exact code here? :(